# why $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos 2x}{\sin x-\cos x}=-\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I have this very simple limit to find
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos (2x)}{\sin x-\cos x}$$
which is equal to $-\sqrt{2}$. However I can get the outcome as mentioned, or $\sqrt{2}$ in the following way:
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos (2x)}{\sin x-\cos x}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos ^2x-\sin^2x}{\sin x-\cos x}=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)}{\sin x-\cos x}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}} (\sin x+\cos x)=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\sqrt{2}$$
Why the mentioned solution method is wrong?
Is limit outcome dependent on the expression rearrangement?

Comment: Hint: $\cos x - \sin x \neq \sin x - \cos x$

Comment: lol... I missed that one :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that  $$\cos x-\sin x\not=\sin x-\cos x.$$ 
We have
$$\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)}{\sin x-\cos x}=\frac{-(\color{red}{\sin x-\cos x})(\cos x+\sin x)}{\color{red}{\sin x-\cos x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit never depend from the expression rearrangements: it is unique (because you are working in $\Bbb R$ with euclidean metric, which makes it an Hausdorff space). For example you can solve your limit using de l'Hopital rule as well:
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}4}\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin x-\cos x}=
\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}4}\frac{-2\sin(2x)}{\cos x+\sin x}=\frac{-2}{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt2}2}=-\sqrt2\;\;.
$$